# Wrapping C++ template function/method in Cython

Tags: c++, templates, methods, cython, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap some C++ Code with Cython. I have a class that utilizes a template method, but is not a template itself.

```
class SomeClass {
    template <class T> SomeClass(T& spam);
};
```

As the class is not a template but only the Constructor, I cannot declare the class as a template in Cython like this.

```
# wrong!
cdef extern from "SomeClass.h":
    cppclass SomeClass [T]:
        SomeClass(T& spam)
```

## How can I wrap the template-method?

Comment: Cython's support for C++ is still very limited, so most likely, you can't. I don't know for sure, though. One workaround that comes to mind is specifying overloads for types you actually use this constructor with.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-constructor template method, using the following non-template class:

```
class SomeClass {
    template <class T> void other(T& spam);
};
```

I was able to get this to work:

```
cdef extern from "someclass.h":
    cppclass SomeClass:
        void other[T](T &spam)
```

That may not help you if you specifically need a constructor template method, but it does appear that Cython's support for template methods has improved at least slightly since the time when this question was originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. (Or I think it is) In the C++ class, the member is templated, whereas in Cython, you declare the class to be templated. Change your code either to:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClass {
    SomeClass(T& spam);
};
```

If feasible, or to:

```
cdef extern from "SomeClass.h":
    cppclass SomeClass:
        SomeClass [T](T& spam)
```

If Cython supports it.

I'm not a cython expert, so I may be wrong.

Comment: The former isn't feasible/equivalent, and the latter doesn't work as presented. (It would be interesting to know if there is some support or some workaround.)

Comment: As of version 0.19, the documentation only mentions template classes, not template methods. http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

Comment: As per [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#what-s-new-in-cython-v0-13-about-c), template methods don't appear to be supported, only template calsses

Answer (score -1):

How about Boost wrapper for cython?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html

Welcome to version 2 of Boost.Python, a C++ library which enables seamless interoperability between C++ and the Python programming language. The new version has been rewritten from the ground up, with a more convenient and flexible interface, and many new capabilities, including support for:
References and Pointers
Globally Registered Type Coercions
Automatic Cross-Module Type Conversions
Efficient Function Overloading
C++ to Python Exception Translation
Default Arguments
Keyword Arguments
Manipulating Python objects in C++
Exporting C++ Iterators as Python Iterators
Documentation Strings

I guess you are looking for something like this , it is already there as part of boost c++ library

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say.